# SSD causes UEFI to load very slow on reboot (~15 sec)

Tags: ssd, performance, sata, uefi

I've recently bought an ADATA Premier Pro SP900 128 GB M.2 . It works fine , it's fast , but I have one issue with it .

When I start the laptop , UEFI loads fast in a second or so , goes to my bootloader (I have a arch linux / windows 8.1 dual boot) , loads windows in about 6-7 seconds and everything is fine .

If I try to reboot however ... UEFI takes about 15 seconds to load and show me the bootloader . After that windows loads just as fast . Its load is also delayed when I try to enter UEFI after reboot . It also has the same behaviour without linux or the bootloader (systemd-boot , a variant of gummiboot) .

My SATA controller is set to AHCI in UEFI and my laptop is a clevo p650 . I'm running a SSD / HDD configuration , with the SSD holding windows and /root , while the HDD is used for storage (downloads , movies , pagefile , /home etc) .

These issues only occur on reboot . If I power off my laptop and immediately power it on , the issue is no longer present and UEFI loads fast ... until I reboot .

I know the issue is the SSD because my UEFI loaded fine and fast with only the HDD present .

What could be the issue ?

Thanks for reading my post and I hope you can help me !

Comment: Have you already tried to upgrade for Firmware Versions? SSD, UEFI, ...

Comment: SSD firmware is up to date . For UEFI there is only one update , but it doesn't fix anything serious . My UEFI is loading slow only on reboot ... first boot it's loading fast . Also Windows boot speed is unaffected by reboot

Comment: A wild and vague guess: Maybe rebooting is triggering something TRIM-related, like the SSD re-organizing or erasing unused cells. If so, I don't know what could be done to "fix" the "problem," since it's not really broken if I'm right. You might look into tools that modify TRIM options, but I don't have any specific suggestions.

Comment: It seems that I'm having very similar problem. Did you manage to find the solution for it?